# Getting the key and value of an object in javascript via 'for in'

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am beginning a exercise to create a quiz in javascript. Anyway, I have an array which contains the questions; each question is a anonymous object...

```
var allQuestions = [{
"question": "Who was Luke's wingman in the battle at Hoth?",
"choices": ["Dak", "Biggs", "Wedge", "fx-7"],
"correctAnswer": 0},
{
"question": "What is the registry of the Starship Reliant?",
"choices": [ "NX-01", "NCC-1864", "NCC-1701", "NCC-2000"],
"correctAnswer": 1}...etc.
```

At this point i'd like to simply iterate through them and insert them into the DOM.

```
var output = '';

for (key in allQuestions[0]) {
        output += '<li>' + allQuestions[0] + '</li>';
    }

 var update = document.getElementById("question");

 update.innerHTML = output;
```

But all I get is:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

At some point i'd like to match or have 'question', 'choices' flow in to corresponding elements on the page....

```
<h2>question</h2> //question from object
<ul id="question">
 <li>choice</li> //choice from object
 <li>choice</li>
 <li>choice</li>
 <li>choice</li>
```

Comment: You’re not _accessing_ anything using the key, all you do is (try to) output `allQuestions[0]` multiple times – and since that _is_ an object, you are only _getting_ `[object Object]` when that is put into a string context …

Comment: In your loop you need to access the properties of the object: `allQuestions[0].key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `allQuestions[0]` inside the loop, but you probably meant to refer to `key`:

```
for (key in allQuestions[0]) {
    output += '<li>' + key + '</li>';
}
```

However, this will return `question`, `choices`, `correctAnswer`. If the items in `allQuestions` are in the same format you're better off looping over them and referring to the relevant properties:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) { 
  var item = allQuestions[i];
  console.log(item.question);
  console.log(item.choices);
  // etc. 
}
```

Comment: That works! But it spits out all the questions and their respective answers, on the page. I'd like to show just the first question and answer.

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz if you just want to work with the first item then in my code get rid of the `for` loop and replace `allQuestions[i]` with `allQuestions[0]` to grab the first item at index 0. The rest of the code would still apply.

Comment: Thanks! One thing though. I tried:
`var answerOutput = "";
for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
var item = allQuestions[0];
        answerOutput += "<li>" + item.choices[i] + "</li> <br/>";

};

var update = document.getElementById("answers");

update.innerHTML = answerOutput;`

And it shows the first choices in the Array but I also get 6 undefined. I tried to hook up a second `for loop` but that crashed the browser. I suspect the solution is simpler.

Thanks!